# Application of nn.Linear layer in pytorch on additional dimentions

Tags: pytorch, tensor

How is the fully-connected layer (`nn.Linear`) in pytorch applied on "additional dimensions"? The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#linear) says, that it can be applied to connect a tensor `(N,*,in_features)` to `(N,*,out_features)`, where `N` in the number of examples in a batch, so it is irrelevant, and `*` are those "additional" dimensions. Does it mean that a single layer is trained using all possible slices in the additional dimensions or are separate layers trained for each slice or something yet different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `in_features * out_features` parameters learned in `linear.weight` and `out_features` parameters learned in `linear.bias`. You can think of `nn.Linear` working as

1. reshape the tensor to some `(N', in_features)`, where `N'` is the product of `N` and all dimensions described with `*`: `input_2d = input.reshape(-1, in_features)`
2. Apply a standard matrix-matrix multiplication `output_2d = linear.weight @ input_2d`.
3. Add the bias `output_2d += linear.bias.reshape(1, in_features)` (notice we broadcast it across all `N'` dimensions)
4. Reshape the output to have the same dimensions as `input`, aside from the last one: `output = output_2d.reshape(*input.shape[:-1], out_features)`
5. `return output`

So the leading dimension `N` is treated the same as the `*` dimensions. The documentation makes `N` explicit to let you know that the input has to be *at least* 2d, but can be as many dimensional as you wish.

Comment: To check my understanding, this effectively means that a single layer (=one set of `in_features * out_features` weights and `out_features` biases) is trained al all slices through the additional dimentions (thus we get `N'` training examples instead of original `N`). Is that a valid re-wording of your answer?

Comment: Yes. I didn't phrase it this way because I wasn't sure if I understood the way you wanted to slice it, but yes, there are `N'` examples.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was trying to figure this out myself today and came up with some working code based on [Jatentaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4280242/jatentaki)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54444882/490982) that helped it click for me. I wanted to share in case it's helpful.

Notes:

- For simplicity, I left out the bias
- [Jatentaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4280242/jatentaki) says that the matrix multiplication looks like `output_2d = linear.weight @ input_2d`, but I found that the matrix dimensions don't line up that way. But the equivalent of `input_2d @ linear.weight.T` worked for me (and that's how the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html#torch.nn.Linear) describe the linear transformation: [image: y = xA^T +b]).

```py
B = 2 # batches
T = 5 # tokens

in_features = 27 
out_features = 10 

# Create an input tensor of shape (B, T, in_features)
x = torch.randn(B, T, in_features)

# Create a linear layer that transforms from in_features to out_features
linear_layer = nn.Linear(in_features, out_features, bias=False)

# Check the shape of the weight matrix
w = linear_layer.weight
assert w.shape == (out_features, in_features)

# Compute result by matrix multiplication
matmul_result = (x.reshape(-1, in_features) @ w.T).reshape(*x.shape[:-1], out_features)

# Compute result by calling the layer
call_result = linear_layer(x)

# Assert they are equal 
assert torch.all(matmul_result == call_result).item() is True
```